# Using an array of custom objects

Tags: java, android, arrays

Let's say I've created an array of objects SpecialResource via

```
ArrayList<SpecialResource> masterRes = new ArrayList<SpecialResource>();
masterRes.add(0, new SpecialResource(3,5,0,"Foo Bar"));
.........etc etc many more adds...
```

Let's say SpecialResource has a method called`getMax()`

How would I reference the `getMa`x method of array index 0?  Every permutation I've guessed at is giving syntax errors. `masterRes<0>.getMax()`, `masterRes(0).getMax()`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually, it's not an array, but a collection. And, in order to retrieve its items by index, you must use the `get` method:

```
masterRes.get(0).getMax();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.   Thank you.  This is a world of difference from python  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
masterRes.get(0).getMax();
```

Java/Android API document will help you.

http://androidappdocs.appspot.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html